# GoogleOpenIdClient.verifyauthentication() result not successful sometimes under IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetopenauth

I have an `ASP.NET MVC 4` webapp using `Google OpenId`. The application works fine whenever I release a new version of my app, authentication will fail for the first couple of times. The problem is, it's not a consequent error. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. So it's really hard to tell what's causing the issue. However, I do know where the problem is. In my code, I check `if (!result.IsSuccessful){...}` and sometimes the `IsSuccessful` property is `false`. But I don't know when it will be false and when it will be true because there is no logical pattern in it. Does anyone have the same issue and know how to solve this? I would like to know what is happening behind the scene in `GoogleOpenIdClient.verifyauthentication()` because that's where the result is set. So this method determines the IsSuccessful property, I guess. Anybody has an idea?